# Symfony 4.1 2 Forms

Tags: symfony

i'm using the last version of symfony 4.1

On my HomePage i have 2 forms. it's the same one. but different location.

one on the top , and one on the bottom.

So until now i did form factory with Name builder

```
    # form top
    $form1 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('order_form', ContactType::class)->getForm();
    $form1->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form1->getData());
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'message');
    }
    # form layout
    $form2 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('quick_contact', ContactType::class)->getForm();
    $form2->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form2->getData());
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'message');
    }
    return $this->render('Site/HomePage.html.twig', ['form1' => $form1->createView(), 'form2' => $form2->createView()]);
}
```

there is another good solution to do it on symfony 4.1?

maybe changing the form to service and call it from twig?

i don't have any idea how to make it better.

thanks!

Comment: pos off-topic here and better for code-review SE?

Comment: You can try the answer below but I'm not sure it will work.  If the duplicate code bothers you them move it to it's own method and share it.  You could also try [embedding a controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html) in your template.  Might not be worth the effort if your contact forms only show up on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Do It in That way:

```
public function HomePage(Request $request)
{
    # form top
    $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($form->getData());
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'message');
    }
    return $this->render('Site/HomePage.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView(), 'form2' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

On The Twig:

Form 1:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Form 2:

```
{{ form_start(form2) }}
{{ form_end(form2) }}
```

Tested on my Symfony.

working without any issues